# Need to use 2 versions of jquery 1.7.2 and 1.8.2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, conflict

I have an confliction problema, i need to use two versions of jquery at the same page, need the 1.7.2 is an function that i use to get from other page in php data from database according by a select change and i need the 1.8.2 to make my form validation, but i just can do one or other, if i try the two that just doesnt work.

I try to use jquery noconflict but i dont understand that so well, maybe i did that wrong or doesnt work.

the function that need 1.7.2:

```
            function getmes(dropdown)
   {
     ano = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/mes.php",
            dataType: "html",
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            data: {
                ano: ano
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#mes").append(result.replace(/[\r\n]+(?=[^\r\n])/g,''));
            }
            });
    }
```

and this is the function that need 1.8.2:

```
var dataForm = new VarienForm('form-id', true);
```

Comment: have a look at [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: It *really* looks like a XY problem. What you probably *need* is to ensure that all your code works with latest jquery.

Comment: refactor your old code for the newer version

Comment: What's the error you get with 1.8.2 when you use it on the function that you claim needs 1.7.2? In the posted code, I don't see what could be conflicting with the newer version.

Comment: The best solution would be remove the need for two separate versions. There really shouldn't be a reason for needing this.

Comment: If your code doesn't work anymore with newer jQuery versions, then you should consider it *deprecated*. It should therefore be updated according to the latest changes made to the jQuery API.

Comment: Also bear in mind that jQuery is now at v1.11. In an ideal world, you wouldn't be using either 1.7 or 1.8 any more. If you have code that relies on either of them, you should be considering updating it to work with the latest release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how you could accomplish this if absolutely necessary:

```
<script src="jquery.1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>
/* Here, you can use $ with your jQuery 1.7.2 code, 
ie. use jQuery 1.7.2 as you normally would.*/
jQuery172 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
/*Now, you can no longer use $. Use jQuery172 with your jQuery 1.7.2
code here, ie. replacing "$" with "jQuery172" in your code.*/
</script>
<script src="jquery.1.8.2.js"></script>
<script>
/*Here, you can use $ again, but now with your jQuery 1.8.2 code, 
ie. use jQuery 1.8.2 as you normally would.*/
jQuery182 = jQuery.noConflict();
/*Now, you can no longer use $. Here, you can use jQuery172 with your 
jQuery 1.7.2 code and use jQuery182 with your jQuery 1.8.2 code.*/
</script>
```

However, I'd recommend refactoring your code in order to support the newer version. Loading two versions of jQuery means twice as much bandwidth on each page load. It's a burden for both your server (unless you're using a CDN) and the client. In addition, the browser will have to construct the jQuery object twice, which is certainly bad for performance, although it may not be noticeable on more recent computers.

Comment: Please note that this solution would actually be very heavy when implemented. Consider this is in last resort, or for testing purposes. (Using Google Hosting Libraries would also please your bandwidth : https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery)

Comment: i'm sorry i'm new at jquery but just explain me, how do i use that JQuery172 in the code? i put that in place of $?

Comment: Yes, like this: jQuery172.ajax({ ... }). Of course, you can pick a different variable name, eg. $7.

Comment: muito obrigado gente consegui descobrir o que era que tava dando conflito usando o console do firebug e apliquei o que o alethes disse só neles e funciono agora